# How to add a value in a list inside another list that already exists?

Tags: c#

I have a list, which in turn is of type **List**, with the constructor what I do is save certain info, and what I have coded is what next:

```
   List<List<string>> opciones = new List<List<string>>();
    public Opcion(){
    var opcionesC = File.ReadAllText(this.dir).Split(";R;").ToList();
    opcionesC.RemoveAll(item => item == "");
    for(int i=0;i<opcionesC.Count;i++){
        this.opciones.Add(new List<string>());
        string[] opc= opcionesC[i].Split("\n");
        foreach(var t in opc){
            if(t.IndexOf("Marc")!=-1){
                this.opciones[i].Add(t);//Solo se añade este de aqui.
            }
            if(t.IndexOf("Model")!=-1){
                this.opciones[i].Add(t.Remove(0,5));//El problema es esto, no se quiere añadir.
            }
            if(t.IndexOf("Tip")!=-1){
                this.opciones[i].Add(t.Remove(0,3)); //El problema es esto, no se quiere añadir.
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Then when doing an output I get this:

```
Marca: Audi
Marca: BMW
```

And what I need is an output like that:

```
Marca: Audi
Modelo: A4
Tipo: Turismo
Marca: BMW
Modelo: S3
Tip:...
```

The file txt its lile this:

```
;Marca; Adui
;Modl; A4
;Tip; Turismo
;Marca; BMW
;Modl; S3
;Tip; Turismo
```

Someone could tell me where the bug is, Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a sample of your input file?

Comment: How are you showing your data for output? TBH creating a class that would represent this data would be a great first start.

Comment: Parallel collections/arrays to store data related to a single entity is clumsy, inefficient and error prone.  Use a Class and a `List<T>`  Also, finding and fixing bugs is the job of The Great Bug Creator (you).  
**[Debugging your code using the  built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** is easier than you think.

Comment: @Steve yes, look and thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have two models from the same brand in that file? As some other people has already told you, using a list of strings to keep this data is not the best way. A List of a specific type or better a dictionary with the brand as key and a list of each model as value are superior solutions to your problem

Comment: @Steve Yes I know, but I only need to store the data since the add is not done correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first choice in a task like this would be to define a class to represent an auto model.
Something like this

```
public class AutoModel
{ 
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

then I would change your loop to read line by line and then trying to interpret the line content

```
AutoModel model = null;
List<AutoModel> autos = new List<AutoModel>();
foreach (string b in File.ReadLines(@"e:\auto.txt"))
{
    string[] data = b.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (data[0] == "Marca")
    {
        if (model != null) autos.Add(model);
        model = new AutoModel { BrandName = data[1].Trim()};
    }
    if(data[0] == "Modl") model.ModelName = data[1].Trim();
    if(data[0] == "Tip") model.TypeName = data[1].Trim();
}
if (model != null) autos.Add(model);
```

At the end you have a `List<AutoModel>` with the content of your file.

If you really do not want to use this way but just a list containing a list of string then you can adapt the same method above as

```
List<string> current = null;
List<List<string>> info = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (string b in File.ReadLines(@"e:\auto.txt"))
{
    string[] data = b.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (data[0] == "Marca")
    {
        if (current != null) info.Add(current);
        current = new List<string>();
        current.Add(data[1].Trim());
    }
    if (data[0] == "Modl") current.Add(data[1].Trim());
    if (data[0] == "Tip") current.Add(data[1].Trim());
}
if (current != null) info.Add(current);
```

Of course I would really advice you to use the first structured approach.